# English words (ONE, TWO, THREE) to number(1,2,3) in ruby

Tags: ruby, numbers, words

I am trying to convert words/strings to numbers in Ruby for example:-

```
ONE => 1 
TWO => 2  
THREE => 3 
FOUR => 4 
etc...
```

I have seen many examples other way around (numbers to words); however, I am not been able to find an example of how to convert words to numbers. It would be great if I can get any insight or help on this.

Comment: I was trying to do it using case or hash but that seems laborious.

Comment: Are you looking to code your own solution or use a library? How high do the numbers have to go to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a hash up-to twenty for all words and only for tens(thirty, forty, fifty etc.). Using Reg-ex took off two words and added them for example twenty two is addition of 20+2=22; right now my script only works till hundred, but it can be extended for numbers over 100 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: http://www.rubyquiz.com/quiz25.html

EDIT: read the question incorrectly. As per my comment below, here's a way you could approach this.

If num_to_word(number) is your method of converting from a number to a word:

```
def number_hash_creator(min, max)
    number_hash = {}
    for num in (min..max)
        number_hash[num_to_word(num)] == num
    end
    number_hash
end
```

Then do something like:

```
number_hash = number_hash_creator(min, max) # min and max are whatever you need them to be

number_hash['three']
=> 3
```

You could also append a similar method to the string class so that you could do things like `"three".to_number`

Comment: But he already said he can find examples the other way around.  The quiz was for number->description.

Comment: True, I read the opposite for some reason. If he can convert numbers to words he could do something like this to create a hash and then check words against the hash. Other than that, there could be a library or something somewhere that does this but I've never heard of it.

Comment: Thank you all for your insight. @jimmydief - I didn't tried the one you posted that might work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find this tutorial very interesting particularly the code near the bottom:

http://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/?Chapter=08